# Append parameters to parameter server using YAML files

Tags: ros, roslaunch, yaml, parameter-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there a way to avoid overwriting parameters when being loaded from a launchfile using a YAML file?

For example, I have two YAML files like the following:

config1.yaml

```
topics:
  - topic: topic1
    type: geometry_msgs/Twist
  - topic: topic2
    type: std_msgs/Empty
```

config2.yaml

```
topics:
  - topic: topic3
    type: geometry_msgs/Twist
  - topic: topic4
    type: std_msgs/Empty
```

and want to have the 4 topics loaded under the `topics` parameter.

I know that namespacing is the way it's normally done to separate parameters with the same name, but I'm looking for some other way.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207133/append-parameters-to-parameter-server-using-yaml-files/) by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 962 on 2015-04-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not as of yet. But there's [a ticket](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/77) for it!

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2015-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) on 2015-06-30**:
thanks! didn't see that ticker before